# ScrollView Android

Tags: android, android-layout

Welcome.

I have a problem with Scrollview.

This is exactly what the buttons that are on the bottom should be every time the same size, and text from checbox should be moved.

What am I doing wrong?

Below is the code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvKtorePytanie"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:text="1/10" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView"
        android:layout_width="220dp"
        android:layout_height="180dp"
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        android:layout_gravity="center" />

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPytanie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Pytanie"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPoprzednie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Poprzednie" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSprawdz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sprawdź" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNastepne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Następne" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Maybe you can be more clear about what you are trying to do, and what is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvKtorePytanie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right"
            android:text="1/10" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="220dp"
            android:layout_height="180dp"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">

        <LinearLayout
            xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
            android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tvPytanie"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                android:text="Pytanie"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz1"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz2"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />

            <CheckBox
                android:id="@+id/cbOdpowiedz3"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="1dip"
                android:text="CheckBox"
                android:textSize="10sp" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <LinearLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="bottom"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bPoprzednie"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Poprzednie" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bSprawdz"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Sprawdź" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/bNastepne"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:text="Następne" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: i post ur code with some changes in linear layout apply weights in layout check it

Answer (score 0):

`ScrollView` contains all the width of the available screen. You have to give fixed (static) height in dpi or px, so that you can set the button right below the `ScrollView`.

Comment: Super it helps, but if we have different screen resolution is a shame to lose the place. Therefore, I seek a universal solution.

Comment: Use dpi, It will solve your problem to some extent, since it uses screen density per inch. Other solution is that, get the screen height and set the height of ScrollView in code according to the screen height.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout as parent layout.
make "linearLayout2" make this as alignParentBottom="true"

Comment: Okay, I used RelativeLayout, but now I have this problem:
http://img14.imageshack.us/img14/69/123siy.jpg I wanted the subtitles did not fall under the buttons.

Answer (score 0):

try this output

```
<LinearLayout 
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true">
      <----put your items here---->
</LinearLayout>
```